# php : email sending failed with more than one attachment

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

I am trying to implement mail functionality in php, its working fine with single attachment, but problem is when I am trying to send more than one attachment, its not working. I am using php mail() function for sending emails, I am trying to attach a PDF and an Image file. If PDF attach then Image won't attach, if Image attach then PDF won't attach. Any thoughts where I'm doing wrong?

```
$header       .= 'From: test <noreply@test.ae>' . "\r\n";       
$header       .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$file           = '1.png'
$displayname    = '1.png';
$file_size     = filesize($file);
$handle        = fopen($file, "r");
$content       = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content       = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid           = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name          = basename($file);

$filepdf        = '1.pdf'
$displaynamepdf= '1.pdf';
$file_sizepdf  = filesize($filepdf);
$handlepdf     = fopen($filepdf, "r");
$contentpdf    = fread($handlepdf, $file_sizepdf);
fclose($handlepdf);
$contentpdf    = chunk_split(base64_encode($contentpdf));
$name          = basename($file);

$header       .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header       .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header       .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header       .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header       .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header       .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$header       .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header       .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$displayname."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
$header       .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header       .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$displayname."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header       .= $content."\r\n\r\n";

$header       .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$displaynamepdf."\"\r\n"; // use different contentpdf types here
$header       .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header       .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$displaynamepdf."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header       .= $contentpdf."\r\n\r\n";
$header       .= "--".$uid."--";

if (mail($to, $subject, "", $header)) {
   return 'sent';
} else {
    return 'not sent';
}
```

Comment: My 2¢: Try to use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: Yea, use a library if you can - there's a lots of problems that took lots of smart people a lot of time to figure out. I like PHPMailer. The problem can be minor and dependent of your type of SMTP server. A library would handle these problems.

Comment: Mihai already touches on this point, but php `mail()` is usually inadequate for any real projects. I suggest PHPMailer. It takes 5 minutes to set up and is very powerful. I do not recommend any PEAR mail modules.

Comment: @Mihai I have never used swiftmailer. Any advantages over PHPMailer?

Comment: @Mihai i got solution with PHPMailer thanks a lot for your suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHPMailer](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html) is the best to use for email.

checkout some below links which will help you in future also:

1. [File Attachments in PHP Mail with PHPMailer](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html#File_Attachments_PHP_Mail_PHPMailer)
2. [php mailer attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876228/php-mailer-attachments)
3. [attachments using phpMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322610/phpmailer-attachment)
4. [PHPMailer Tutorial](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial)
5. [A Simple Example : Sending Email with Attachment Using
   Phpmailer](http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/a-simple-example-sending-email-with-attachment-using-phpmailer/)
6. [PHP send email with multiple attachments with PHPMailer with SMTP
   Authentication](http://4rapiddev.com/php/phpmailer-send-email-with-attachments-via-smtp-authentication/)
7. [Sending email with multiple attachments with PHP](http://kanakvaghela.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/sending-email-with-multiple-attachments-with-php/)

may this help you.

Comment: PHPMailer is the best option and easy to implement also thanks for suggestion

Comment: @user2172726 welcome!!! We are here to help each other.... so thanks to Stack Overflow!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have `$file` and `$filepdf` both set to '1.png'. Set `$filepdf="1.pdf"` so that the rest of the header is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for multiple attachments in mail function..

I have created the function for multiple attachment . and check this.

```
/* 
     * Function Name: sentMail
     * Scope        : Sent Mail Function with CC , BCC and Attachment files..
     * Input        : Recipient Name            => $recipientName   // (Required)
     *                Recipient MailId(Many)    => $recipientMailId // (Required & Array Format)
     *                Subject Content           => $subjectContent  // (Required)
     *                Message Content           => $messageContent  // (Required)
     *                Sender MailId             => $senderMailId    // (Required)
     *                Sender Name(Many)         => $senderName      // (Required)
     *                Recipient CC MailId       => $recipientCCMailId   //(Optional & Array Format)
     *                Recipient BCC MailId      => $recipientBCCMailId  //(Optional & Array Format)
     *                Attachment Files          => $attachmentFiles     //(Optional & Array Format)
     * Output       : Sent mail to the Recipient.
     */
    public function sentMail($recipientName,$recipientMailId,$subjectContent,$messageContent,$senderName,$senderMailId,$recipientCCMailId,$recipientBCCMailId,$attachmentFiles)
    {
        try 
        {
            /*Get the Mulitple Recipient CC MailId*/
            if(isset($recipientCCMailId)){
                if(count($recipientCCMailId)>1){
                    $recipientCCMailId = implode(',',$recipientCCMailId);
                }
                else{
                    $recipientCCMailId = $recipientCCMailId[0];
                }
            }

            /*Get the Mulitple Recipient BCC MailId*/
            if(isset($recipientBCCMailId)){
                if(count($recipientBCCMailId)>1){
                    $recipientBCCMailId = implode(',',$recipientBCCMailId);
                }
                else{
                    $recipientBCCMailId = $recipientBCCMailId[0];
                }
            }

            /*** Mail Contents Starts ***/
                $subj = $subjectContent;
                $msg ="";

                /*Get the Mulitple Recipient BCC MailId*/
                if(count($recipientMailId)>1){
                    $recipientMailId = implode(',',$recipientMailId);
                    $msg .="Dear, <b>All</b>\r <br>";
                }
                else{
                    $recipientMailId = $recipientMailId[0];
                    $msg .="Dear, <b>".ucwords($user_name)."</b> \r <br>";
                }
                $msg .=$messageContent."\r <br><br>";
                $msg .="Thank you"."\r\n\n <br>";
                $msg .=$senderName."\r\n\n <br><br>";

                $headers ="";

                /** Get the Mulitple Attachment files and Attachment Process Starts **/
                if(isset($attachmentFiles)){
                    $headers .= "From: ".$senderMailId."\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Cc: ".$recipientCCMailId."\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Bcc: ".$recipientBCCMailId."\r\n";
                    // boundary
                    $semi_rand = md5(time());
                    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

                    // headers for attachment
                    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
                     // multipart boundary
                    $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $msg . "\n\n";

                    // preparing attachments
                    for($i=0;$i<count($attachmentFiles);$i++)
                    {
                        if(is_file($attachmentFiles[$i]))
                        { 
                            $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                            $fp     = @fopen($attachmentFiles[$i],"rb");
                            $data   = @fread($fp,filesize($attachmentFiles[$i]));
                                      @fclose($fp);
                            $data   = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                            $msg .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($attachmentFiles[$i])."\"\n" .
                            "Content-Description: ".basename($attachmentFiles[$i])."\n" .
                            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($attachmentFiles[$i])."\"; size=".filesize($attachmentFiles[$i]).";\n" .
                            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                        }
                     }
                    $msg .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
                }
                /** Attachment Process Ends **/
                else{
                    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
                    //$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "From: ".$senderMailId."\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Cc: ".$recipientCCMailId."\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Bcc: ".$recipientBCCMailId."\r\n";
                }
            /*** Mail Contents Ends ***/    
            $sent_mail=mail($recipientMailId,$subj,$msg,$headers); 
            if($sent_mail)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            getConnection('close');
            echo "Caught Exception:",$e->getMessage();
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This one may help for you.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue. The problem is with mime boundary. Don't add "--".$uid."--"; after every attachment. Adding boundary before content type of attachment is enough.